# Python character handling in terminal

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, terminal, output

I'm in an interactive Python 2.7 Terminal (Terminal default output is "utf-8"). I have a string from the internet, lets call it `a`

```
>>> a
u'M\xfcssen'
>>> a[1]
u'\xfc'
```

I wonder why its value is not `ü` so I try

```
>>> print(a)
Müssen
>>> print(a[1])
ü
```

which works as intended.

So my first question is, what does `print a` do, which is missing if i just type `a`?

and out of curiosity: Why is it that I get another output for the following in the same python terminal session?

```
>>> "ü"
'\xc3\xbc'
>>> print "ü"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print u"ü"
ü
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand how python stores various data types and which functions expect which input. Its all quite confusing and also depends on your LOCALE setting of your terminal.

The following link might help to reduce the confusion: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

All `str` objects like `"My String"` are stored as 8bit per character. In your case `'\xc3\xbc'` is the utf8 representation of the UMLAUT-U as a `str` object.

For `unicode` objects, python uses 16bit or 32bit integer to store the string.

Now the `print` function expects `str` objects as input. That's why the following works.

```
>>> print '\xc3\xbc'
ü
```

To turn the UMLAUT-U from a `str` into a `unicode` object. you have to tell python that the string is in UTF8 representation before you convert it into a `unicode` object.

```
>>> unicode('\xc3\xbc'.decode('utf8'))
u'\xfc'
```

Answer (score 1):

> what does `print a` do, which is missing if i just type `a`?

The interactive `>>>` prompt outputs values using the Python source code representation of the value, as returned by the `repr()` function. That's why you get not just `\xFC` for the `ü` character but also quote marks around the string. The prompt is trying to show you what you would need to type into a Python program to get the string value you have.

The `print` statement outputs the raw string conversion of the value, as returned by the `str()` function.

For some types `repr()` and `str()` generate the same output, but this is not the case for strings.